# subquery with date and max()

Tags: subquery

i have problems with this query. It shall return the max temperature of the day but it returns empty. what have i done wrong?

SELECT *
FROM tempdat
WHERE date( tdate ) = curdate( )
AND temperature = (
SELECT max( temperature )
FROM tempdat ) ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather use:

```
SELECT 
       convert(datetime, convert(varchar(12), tdate ))  AS DayOfTemp
       ,max(temperature)                                   AS MaxTemp
FROM 
    tempdat 
WHERE 
    convert(datetime, convert(varchar(12), tdate )) = convert(datetime, convert(varchar(12, curdate( ) )) 
group by 
    convert(datetime, convert(varchar(12), tdate ))
```

Comment: You will be making sure it caters for any datetimes for that day

Comment: Gives this error: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'convert(varchar(12, tdate )) AS DayOfTemp ,max(temperature) AS MaxTemp ' at line 2

Comment: Sorry, forgot a bracket.

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery returns the overall maximum of the data - not of the day, you need something like:

```
select max(temperature) from tempdat group by tdate having tdate = curdate()
```